# jQuery: Hiding *only* text from <label>

Tags: jquery, html, dom, hide

I have the following markup that is output from a WordPress plugin

```
<div class="emaillist">
    <form action="#" method="post">
        <div class="es-field-wrap">
            <label>Name*<br>
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" value="" required="" class="form-control">
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="es-field-wrap">
            <label>Email*<br>
            <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="Email" required=""></label>
        </div>                              

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Subscribe">
    </form>
</div>
```

I am trying to hide the `Name` and `Email` text within the `<label>` fields like so:

```
$('.form-blog-notify label').text('')
```

But when I do that, it removes the `input` fields from the DOM also

Is there a way I can hide the text whilst leaving the text fields in place?

Comment: Do you want the text removed or would it work to make it not visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the first text node and then remove it. Where you can use [`contents()`](https://api.jquery.com/contents/) method to get all child nodes including text nodes.

```js
$('label').each(function() {
  $(this).contents().first().remove()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="emaillist">
  <form action="#" method="post">
    <div class="es-field-wrap">
      <label>Name*<br>
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" value="" required="" class="form-control">
            </label>
    </div>
    <div class="es-field-wrap">
      <label>Email*<br>
            <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="Email" required=""></label>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Subscribe">
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Font Size to `0`. Now the text does not show, but still be in the HTML.

```css
.es-field-wrap label {
  font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="emaillist">
  <form action="#" method="post">
    <div class="es-field-wrap">
      <label>Name*<br><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" value="" required="" class="form-control"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="es-field-wrap">
      <label>Email*<br><input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="Email" required=""></label>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Subscribe">
  </form>
</div>
```

If you want to remove the text, then jQuery is better.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".es-field-wrap label").each(function(i, el) {
    $(el).contents()[0].remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="emaillist">
  <form action="#" method="post">
    <div class="es-field-wrap">
      <label>Name*<br><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" value="" required="" class="form-control"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="es-field-wrap">
      <label>Email*<br><input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="Email" required=""></label>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Subscribe">
  </form>
</div>
```